# Free font creators with multi color support

Tags: software-recommendation, font-design

I have heard of good free font creating tools like Birdfont and Fontforge but I would like to know if there is any one that supports multi colored fonts. I know transtype by fontlab supports this but price is out of my budget for now especially since I'm just doing this for the fun of it.

Comment: Not a lot of systems support color fonts at the moment... Let along the problem that colors are encoded differently whether you want to print or display on a screen.... But I'm curious to see if a tool exists

Comment: You can export embedded SVG files with the commercial version of Birdfont. It is pretty cheap.

Answer (score 2):

I know [Fontself](https://www.fontself.com/) (which I haven't tried yet but really looks awesome) will soon include this feature.

While not free it is still less expensive than Transtype and allows you to directly make fonts within Illustrator - which is its main purpose, in fact it is an Illustrator plugin.

However I don't now any totally free software which can do this...

Comment: Do you mind expanding on what Fontself is?  At this time this answer can be taken as a link only answer.  Please add more detail or your answer may be removed.

Comment: Sorry for this. Is it better now ?