# Create a custom font with multi colours

Tags: color, fonts, tools, font-design

I'm looking to crate a custom font. The font has 2 colours - a coloured fill and a different coloured hard edge shadow. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Related: [Can TrueType fonts contain color?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64917/can-truetype-fonts-contain-color) and [Free font creators with multi color support](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71337/free-font-creators-with-multi-color-support)

Comment: Did you have an example for that? I think every font has just one color...what if you want to change the color in Photoshop or Illustrator?

Comment: what about emoji fonts?

Comment: Okey sorry .. doesn't thought about that ;) ... but I found something interesting ... you need to create two glyphs one is the background and the other the colored fill and if there are three colors you need 3 svg's for one glyph (bg, color1, color2) and so on ... this works with transtype 4 but search for it...you can find it easily with google

Comment: No need to be sorry. I was simply challenging the statement that fonts are only one color

Comment: Thanks, I have had a look into the emojis and it seems they only work for apple. I need something that would work for anyone in my clients office.

Comment: @Cai I'm not aware of any emoji font that comes multi-colored for use with standard DTP software.

Comment: @DA01 I didn't say anything about any software :)

Answer (score 2):

Font files (well, *most* types of font files) don't contain any color information...which makes sense as the designer is the one that has to choose the color.

For creating fonts that ultimately will be nice to have rendered in multiple colors, the typical solution is to separate the parts you want as different colors and put them into separate glyphs. The designer can then layer the type using the different glyphs in their editing software.

This is often called a 'chromatic' font. Many examples:

http://www.myfonts.com/search/chromatic/

Here's one of those examples showing the multiple glyphs that can be combined to make a multi-colored letterform:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I need to make the font as that it can be used by anyone in my clients office.

Comment: @RFarrell define 'anyone'. What software? Alas, there is no native widely-supported font format that supports multiple colors by default.

Comment: Hey DA01, Yep I don't think I can do what I want to do. But thank you for your help.